# Why is my JSON showing up in Kendo UI as Datasource.options.data but not Datasource.data?

Tags: json, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

New to Kendo and I'm having a tough time getting my JSON data to display in the Kendo Grid.  If i reference my $scope.actionData through a normal html table, i'm able to view it in the page.

Ultimately I'm trying to accomplish [this](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/Grid)

The column headers display on the page, but no data beneath them.

When I'm attempting to populate the kendo grid, I can see the data I'm expecting through the Chrome Kendo UI Inspector in the DataSource -> Options -> Data Array, but I can't figure out how to get it to display on the page, and it's not populating the DataSource -> Data array.  I've tried working through the examples on the angular-kendo page, but no luck.  I've also tried adding various elements/tags under the div in the html, but I'm back where I started.

Let me know if I need to add anything else.  Any assistance getting this to populate is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div kendo-grid k-data-source="gridOptions"></div>
```

Controller:

```
var actionHistoryControllers = angular.module('actionHistoryControllers', ['kendo.directives'])
        .controller('ActionHistoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'ActionHistory',
             function ($scope, $routeParams, ActionHistory) {
                 $scope.actionData = ActionHistory.query({ appid: $routeParams.appid },
                       function (data) {
                           $scope.error = false;
                           $scope.errorMsg = "";
                       },
                       function (data) {
                           $scope.error = true;
                           $scope.errorMsg = "<strong>Unable to load!</strong> Please reload the page.";
                       });

                 $scope.gridOptions = {
                     data: $scope.actionData,
                     columns: [
                         {field: "UserID", title: "User ID"},
                         {field: "ActionText", title: "Action Text"}]
                 }
              }])
```

Chrome Kendo UI Inspector:

```
Data source
   options: Object{9} 
   data: Array[3] 
      0: Object{17} 
        ActionHistoryID: 315911
        ActionText: "System"
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the following:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
                     data: $scope.actionData,
                     columns: [
                         {field: "UserID", title: "User ID"},
                         {field: "ActionText", title: "Action Text"}]
                 }
```

with the following:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: function (o) {                        
                            o.success($scope.actionData);
                        }
                    },
                     columns: [
                         {field: "UserID", title: "User ID"},
                         {field: "ActionText", title: "Action Text"}]
                }
}
```